# Matching ArrayList and Byte Array in SQL query

Tags: java, sql, jpa

I'm implementing a program java and jpa.
I have would like to compare the ArrayList in the search function. And in my table of database, I keep the data which is byte array of string.

I take the parameter in my function with ArrayList but I don't know how to write the query. 
If I use IN, it seems like I have to make a loop and select the data from the table with the loop. Because it compares between a string and a list of string, not list of string and list of string.
Anyone can give me some suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

If your ArrayList is not too big, you can build your statement to use it as a table of UNIONs:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable AS A INNER JOIN (
        SELECT 'ALVal1' AS Val
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 'ALVal2' AS Val
        UNION ALL
        ...
        ) AS B
    ON A.MyVal = B.Val
```

But I may be showing my lack of jpa here... Can you build your own statements?